# How to convert byte array to NSString

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, nsstring

I am reading data from a TCP/IP stream and am successfully receiving a byte array from the pre-existing server. I am now trying to find a way to convert that array to an `NSString`. I have found several examples, but am having a hard time getting my desired results.

```
NSData *data=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];

uint8_t buffer[1024];
unsigned int len=0;

len=[(NSInputStream *)stream read:buffer maxLength:1024];
if(len>0){  

    [data appendBytes:&buffer length:len];
    //BYTE ARRAY OBTAINED OK!!
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //METHOD #1 - Yields 'nil'
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //METHOD #2 - Log prints OK, but messageString says
    //'invalid' in debugger, and get warnings all over the 
    //place. I know this is wrong, but it semi-works :)

    size_t length=[data length];
    unsigned char aBuffer[length];
    [data getBytes:aBuffer length:length];
    aBuffer[length - 1]=0;

    NSString *messageString =aBuffer; 
    NSLog (@"%s",messageString);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}else{
    NSLog(@"No Buffer");
}
```

Please help! Any assistance provided is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got the answer.

I had to change this:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

To this:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                         encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: awesome! I've been struggling with this for 2 days... awesome finding!

Comment: This solution isn't going to work when you receive anything multi-byte. For example "c3 97" is the multiplication sign in UTF-8. If your data buffer only caught the c3 and the 97 is coming in the next buffer then you're in trouble.

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong:

```
[data appendBytes:&buffer length:len];
```

It should be:

```
[data appendBytes:buffer length:len];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString* string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: data];
```

Make sure your data is null-terminated, obviously.