# How to convert the BYTEARRAYS to NSString in objective -c

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsstring

Can any one guide me in this problem ,i have to convert BYTEARRAYS to NSString in objective -c.
Currently im getting Files in the form of byte array i have to convert it to file or string to generate the files.

the response string is

```
<s:Body>
<GetDocumentResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<GetDocumentResult>
PGJpbmRpbmcgbmFtZT0id3NIdHRwQmluZGluZ05vU0NUIj4gICAgICAgICA8c2VjdXJpdHkgbW9kZT0iTm9uZSI+ICAgICAgICAgICA8dHJhbnNwb3J0IGNsaWVudENyZWRlbnRpYWxUeXBlPSJOb25lIiAvPiAgICAgICAgICAgPG1lc3NhZ2UgZXN0YWJsaXNoU2VjdXJpdHlDb250ZXh0PSJmYWxzZSIgLz4gICAgICAgICA8L3NlY3VyaXR5PiAgICAgICA8L2JpbmRpbmc+
</GetDocumentResult>
</GetDocumentResponse>
</s:Body>
```

Kindly guide in this

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone SDK: Convert Byte Array to NSString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738674/iphone-sdk-convert-byte-array-to-nsstring)

Answer (score 0):

Use `initWithData` method of `NSString`.

> **@Dutchie432**  asked and also given the answer.

[How to convert byte array to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738674/iphone-sdk-convert-byte-array-to-nsstring)